# Understanding this JavaScript loop

Tags: for-loop, google-maps-api-3

I am using this for loop to find a specific marker in a googlemaps marker array.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', () => {
  for (var i = 0, I = this.markers.length; i < I && this.markers[i] != marker; ++i);
  this.path.setAt(i, marker.getPosition());
});
```

I understand that when the dragend event is fired the loop is executed, and the code works, but I am having a hard time explaining in plain language how this loop is working. I've never seen a loop written like this and I'd like to better understand how it is working.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, it's using an anonymous function using the ES6 arrow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Secondly, the `for` loop is assigning 2 variables `i` and `I`, rather than just 1.

```
var i = 0, I = this.markers.length;
```

It is also using 2 conditional statements.

```
i < I && this.markers[i] != marker;
```

The loop runs through the list of markers until it finds the last one, and creates a path along those points.

Does this help?

Comment: it does help, I am just confused by the != marker. Wouldn't this stop the loop from executing an operation on the marker I have click, yet the operation does modify marker, that's what's confusing me

Comment: @SethJohnson The loop continues until the current marker referenced by the loop is equal to the final marker.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still confused. I read the loop as, for each element in the length of the array that does not equal the marker execute the operation.

Comment: @SethJohnson Yes... Now I'm confused why you're confused because you seem to understand it :-). The event is `dragend`, so `marker` is going to be the final marker in the path. The loop will execute and set the path up until the final marker.

Comment: I'm sorry that event name is misleading. `dragend` means you're done dragging the marker. This operation updates the position of a marker when you drag it on a map. So the loop should ignore everything BUT the marker that you've currently dragged no?

Answer (score 1):

The loop is the same as the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; ++i)
    if (this.markers[i] == marker)
       { break; }
```

Don't see the point to use a `I` here... fancy one liner

Comment: This makes sense to me, however the code this.markers[i] != marker. Does the loop change what != means? I am doing an operation on marker, so I'm not sure why the loop is doing stuff to everything BUT the marker.

Comment: because it is the loop condition of the for loop. `Loop if A` is the same as `Break if not A`

Answer (score 0):

We initialize two variables, i and I. I is the length of the array, and i begins as zero.

We loop so long as i is less than the length of the array, and also so long as the ith element isn't "marker." Every time we execute the loop, we move on to the next element of the array by incrementing i.

Comment: The operation is supposed to modify 'marker' what is happening such that we are not executing the loop on 'marker'

Answer (score 0):

Statement 1 is executed before the loop (the code block) starts. [the statement before the first semicolon]. Your example is declaring two variables.

Statement 2 defines the condition for running the loop (the code block). [the statement before the second semicolon]. The variables must meed these conditions to execute the loop.

Statement 3 is executed each time after the loop (the code block) has been executed. [the last statement]. Do something after the loop executes.

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp